# How to add results with the same id in sql developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL Developer:
I have a dataset, there are IDs which are not unique. Some of these IDs has a cancellation date. I would like to add the cancellation date to the rows with same ID.
Example:

```
product ; cancellation ; 

a          null             
b          12-01-2019
c          null
d          null
a          23-01-2019
b          null
```

I would like to fill up the nulls, when in the same product there is a cancellation date.

Should look like this:

```
product ; cancellation;   cancelled;

a          null           23-01-2019 
b          12-01-2019     12-01-2019 
c          null           null 
d          null           null 
a          23-01-2019     23-01-2019 
b          null           12-01-2019
```

I have no idea, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT          prod.product,
                prod.cancellation,
                canc.cancellation AS cancelled
FROM            my_table prod
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table canc
             ON prod.product = canc.product
            AND canc.cancellation IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function in a `select`:

```
select t.*, max(cancellation) over (partition by product) as cancelled
from t;
```

If you want to set the value in a query, you can use `update`:

```
update t
    set cancelled = (select max(t2.cancellation)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.product = t.product
                    )
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.product = t.product and
                        t2.cancellation is not null
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly I would do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_first_table 
ADD cancelled DATE;

CREATE TABLE your_temp_table(PRODUCT, CANCELLATION)
AS
SELECT PRODUCT, CANCELLATION 
FROM your_first_table ;

UPDATE your_first_table A 
SET cancelled  = (SELECT CANCELATION 
                  FROM your_temp_table B 
                  WHERE B.PRODUCT  = A.PRODUCT 
                  AND A.CANCELLATION IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE2 T2
USING (SELECT PRODUCT, CANCELLATION FROM TABLE1 
       WHERE CANCELLATION IS NOT NULL) T1
ON (T2.PRODUCT = T1.PRODUCT)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET 
T2.CANCELLED = T1.CANCELLATION;
```

Cheers!!